# WP8 timer app under lock screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have app with dispatcher timer. User set some interval(for example 30 sec) and press button start. App Each 30 sec play sound. All work ok. But when User lock phone timer stopped and nothing played. Can I play sound each 30 sec when phone is locked?

Comment: Yes Sure.

Are you aware with ScheduledTaskAgent in windows phone?

Comment: I will post the answer please refer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to keep the app running under lock screen.

Using [Idle Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css), you can keep the app on, although screen is locked. Actually, it is not running in background, but in the foreground. Just the screen is locked. So, be careful not to drain user's battery.

You have to set the [`PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to `Disabled`, for example in `InitializePhoneApplication()` method in *App.xaml.cs*:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Note that there are special certification requirements for this type of apps. Refer to section 6.3 (Apps running under a locked screen) of the following page:

[Additional requirements for specific app types for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

yes.
sure.. 
You can use the Scheduled Task Agent in windows phone.

using the Scheduled Task Agent, when you app is not running or stopped (not in background).
you can fire your Events.

For that you have to add the scheduled task agent into your project.
And in the `ScheduledAgent.cs` file find the **OnInvoke** method and put your code here.
this method performs the task in Background. (Means the code is executed when your phone is locked).

for more Reference click here **[Implement background agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)**

I hope you get the destination. Now, just put that code into your application and its working.

Comment: Thanks. in OnInvoke I must create new timer and set interval for playing sound?

Comment: Yes. You can create new timer it executes only when your phone is locked (means in background). it does not affect the current project's Timer and Interval.

Comment: The problem with the Periodic Tasks is that they are executed every 30 minutes, and he won't be able to set his desired interval.